# nested loop with differents data

Tags: list, loops, twig, nested-loops

I have two lists:

```
campaigns = [{"name":"test", "client": "test_client", "reporter": "myself", "price": 45}...]
```

```
filters = ["name", "client", "reporter"]
```

I want my table to just display the data contained in the filter.

```
<tbody>
{% for campaign in campaigns %}
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        {% for filter in filters%}
            <td>{{campaign.filter}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Those are 2 differents lists, but I want to use the filters list to get the keys in the campaigns list, I tried multiple writing but it didn't work:

```
{{campaign[filter]}}

{{campaign}}.{{filter}}
```

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/dx1xk3) with `campaign[filter]`. Are you sure the data inside `campaigns` is just an array with assoc indices or are they objects?

Comment: Yes, when I `print(campaign["name"])` it returns the value of `name`. It is a mongo object at first, I turn it into a list in python.

Answer (score -1):

```
<tbody>
    {% for campaign in campaigns %}
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            {% for key, item in campaign.items%}
                {% for filter in filters %}
                    {% if key == filter %}
                        <td>{{item}}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

With this code I was able to retrieve my data in a nested loop. In case this might help someone.